# how to prevent double click event on submit button

Tags: jquery

This is my 'custForgotPass' input button .
When I click on the button I verify the email and send it.
On a doubleclick it sends two emails
I want to prevent the doubleclick.
Nothing is working for me eg. disabling the button, jQuery.on event, disabling dbclick event.

```
$('#custForgotPass').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$("#txtForgotEmail").focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('div').css('display', 'none')
});
var forgotEmail = $('input#txtForgotEmail').val();
var isOk = true;
if (forgotEmail.trim() == '') {
    $('input#txtForgotEmail').parent().find('div').find('div').text('required');
    $('input#txtForgotEmail').parent().find('div').css('display', 'block')
    isOk = false;
} else {
    var pattern = "^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$";
    if (forgotEmail.match(pattern)) {
        $('input#txtForgotEmail').parent().find('div').find('div').text('invalid');
        $('input#txtForgotEmail').parent().find('div').css('display', 'block')
        isOk = false;
    }
}
if (!isOk) {
    return;
}
//$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
var success = '';
var posting = $.post('process/forgot_password.aspx', {
    forgotEmail: encodeURIComponent(forgotEmail)
});
posting.done(function(data) {
    var content = $(data);
    if (data == 'Error') {
        $('#forgot-msg-success').empty().append('Sorry there is technical problem try later.');
        $('#forgot-msg-success').css('display', 'block').fadeIn(600).fadeOut(600).fadeIn(600);
    } else if (data == 'Invalid') {
        $('#forgot-msg-success').empty().append('Invalid email pls try again.');
        $('#forgot-msg-success').css('display', 'block').fadeIn(600).fadeOut(600).fadeIn(600);
    } else {
        $('input#txtForgotEmail').val("");
        $('#forgot-msg-success').empty().append('Password sent on your email address.');
        $('#forgot-msg-success').css('display', 'block').fadeIn(600).fadeOut(600).fadeIn(600);
    }
});
});
});
```

Comment: did you try removing the `ID` when your callback for `click` event starts and adding the `ID` once you are done with email processing?

Comment: yes i want user should click single click

Answer (score 1):

remove the `ID` which is your handler for click event once you are inside callback and add it once your whole processing is done.

```
 $("#submit").on('click', function (event) {  
      $(this).removeAttr('id');
      //do something
      $(this).attr('id', 'submit');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$('#custForgotPass').one('click',function (event) {
 //code
}
```

but you need to reattach later.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").one('click', function (event) {  
       event.preventDefault();
       //do something
       $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
})
```

Comment: Please explain your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.unbind()`

> FOR EXAMPLE:

```
$(".classname").unbind().click(function(event,ui){ ...
```